# How to copy a particular line out of file and add a command to it?

Tags: shell-script

```
#cat /etc/Symantec.conf
[Symantec Shared]
 BaseDir=/opt/symantec
 JAVA_HOME=/opt/symantec/java/jdk1.6.0_27/jre/bin
```

I need a command to copy the line `/opt/symantec/java/jdk1.6.0_27/jre/bin` 
from the above file and then insert `java -version` in front of it.
so it will do the following  command:

```
#/opt/symantec/java/jdk1.6.0_27/jre/bin/java -version
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo $(grep -oP '^\s*JAVA_HOME=\K.*' /etc/Symantec.conf)"/java -version"
    /opt/symantec/java/jdk1.6.0_27/jre/bin/java -version
```

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution:

```
# $(sed -n 3p tt | sed 's/JAVA_HOME=//')/java -version

sed -n Np # print line #N
sed 's//' # replace
```

Answer (score 1):

try:
    `grep -Po "JAVA_HOME=\K.*" /etc/Symantec.conf`/java -version

grep -P allows using a lookbehind in the regex using '\K' and -o returns only the matching part of the regex

surrounding the grep in backticks substitutes it with its result

Answer (score -1):

Another solution:

```
$ printf "$(grep JAVA_HOME /etc/Symantec.conf  | cut -d= -f2)/java --version\n"
/opt/symantec/java/jdk1.6.0_27/jre/bin/java --version
```

If you want to immediately *run* this command:

```
$(printf "$(grep JAVA_HOME /etc/Symantec.conf  | cut -d= -f2)/java --version\n")
```